# How to convert a black-on-white EPS to black-on-transparent in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background-removal, eps

I have been supplied with a logo in .eps format, but it has a white background. I cannot get Illustrator to knock the background out and make the logo black on transparent.

I've tried the magic wand tool, but Illustrator just treats the EPS as a single un-editable entity — all I seem to be able to do with it is resize it.

I can export as a raster format and then knock the background out in Photoshop, of course — but I need to end up with a vector SVG, not a raster

How can I change this background to transparent and still have a scalable vector file at the end of it?

Comment: Are you sure the .eps is vector? Eps has the capacity to embed pixel files, and it looks like yours is one of those cases.

Comment: Hmm — after scaling it up to 3000% in Illustrator, it looks like that's what's happened. Looks like there's not a lot I can do apart from teaching the person who gave me it the difference between vector and raster :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your .eps has a pixel image embedded. Just like .ai and other vector file formats, .eps is capable of having raster images embedded within itself.

The best you could do is use LiveTrace on the pixel image and hope for the best.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing in the end — it hasn't come out too badly, so hopefully it'll do :)